# Adding Columns to Google Drive Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-drive-api

I am using the Php based Google Drive API to create Spreadsheets.
I am able to create the spreadsheets in the drive properly. 
I would like to add columns to the created SpreadSheet document so I can start adding content to it later.

I tried a few things, so mentioning them one after the other. Check the "data" str.
Here's my code:

```
//adding directly
$insertedFile = $dr_service->files->insert($file, array('data' => 'column1,column2,column3', 'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'));

//adding it by passing an array
$insertedFile = $dr_service->files->insert($file, array('data' => array("Column 1" => "data 2" ,"Column 2" => "data 2","Column 3" => "data 3"), 'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'));
```

As I mentioned in my earlier comments, the document is getting created successfully. Just not able to add column names to it.

Looking forward to hearing some solutions,
Thanks,
Mihir.

Answer (score 0):

### Add columns

To add a new column name, use **CellFeed**. CellFeed is part of google-spreadsheet-API.

I assume you are using ListFeed. ListFeed will not let you add columns. List feed is more like SQL. Works a little like SQL style INSERT and SELECT.